# How can i iterate a String and grab several data from there?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this method:

```
public void separator(){
    int count=0, i=0;
    while (count == 0) {
        if (track1result.charAt(i) != '^') {
            char c = track1result.charAt(i);
            number += c;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

It's supposed to iterate a String until he reaches the `^` symbol, and that's great, and working so far, the problem is that i'm not sure how can i like keep going from there so i can get the string that's after the symbol and store it in another variable.
If you can give me ideas i would really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you want to split the string around '^'?

Comment: Why not just use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Yes!, store the data before the ^ in variable: "number" and the data after in "name", but i have tried another while and just left me with an infinite loop

Comment: i didn't know split existed thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the else part add this:

```
if (i < track1result.length() - 1)
    rest = track1result.substring(i + 1);
```

where `rest` is previously declared:

```
String rest = "";
```

Comment: This is a really poor solution--not only for the reason that you are supporting the OP's poor choice of using a loop.

Comment: @Barns Do you know why the OP chose this loop to solve this kind of problem? Don't you know that many questions in SO are just school exercises with restrictions on use of certain methods that would otherwise never been used by a developer?

Comment: Exactly, offer the OP the opportunity to use  this poor example and get an Failing grade on the assignment. They should will be thankful.

Comment: Thanks man, it really helped me out

Comment: @Barns I guess you did not even read my comment. What I'm saying is if the assignment strictly demanded the use of a loop then the OP would not and should not use any other more effective method. Am I clear now?

Answer (score 2):

you can just split the `String` into array

```
String s1 = "hello^world";
    String[] arr = s1.split("\\^");
    String firstpart = arr[0];
    String secondpart = arr[1];
    System.out.println(firstpart+" "+secondpart);
```

Comment: I mean it works but they are stored in the same variable, and i kind of need them in separate variables

Comment: `arr[0]` will return before `^` and `arr[1]` will return after the `^`

Comment: Right!, Thanks!